# Apostrophes converted to &#39; when sending variable to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, jinja2, apostrophe

I sent in the following array of dictionaries through Python to HTML:

`[{'color': '#CFCFC4', 'day': 7}, {'color': '#FDFD96', 'day': 8}]`

which then gets sent to a `Javascript` function using the following line:

```
generateHTML("{{ colors }}");
```

However, while sending the array to Javascript, the apostrophes within the array are converted to `&#39(;)` so that it looks like

```
[{&#39(;)day&#39(;): 7, &#39(;)color&#39(;): &#39(;)#CFCFC4&#39(;)}, {&#39(;)day&#39(;): 8, &#39(;)color&#39(;): &#39(;)#FDFD96&#39(;)}]
```

with the parentheses removed. How can I keep the original form of the array?

Comment: I can't reproduce this (my output is just regular apostrophes), but may I suggest trying to use jinja 2.9's `tojson` filter? It might handle this for you, as well as being safer in general.
http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#tojson

Comment: Also, depending on whether you have autoescaping enabled, this might be what is causing your issue - read this: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#html-escaping